# How to generate SQL insert with hex (blob) content for e.g. a Flyway migration script

Tags: mysql, blob, flyway

How can I generate SQL inserts with hex (blob) content for e.g. a Flyway migration script.

I can open the binary content in an editor, e.g. UltraEdit using Hex mode.  However, cannot find a way to copy and paste this content to my SQL editor, e.g. MySQL Workbench. I can copy a few bytes, but the files I need are around 60k to 100k.

Suggestions please anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After talking to colleagues here, tried this quick process and verified it works OK:-

1. Using MySQL Workbench, right click on the blob field and "Load Value From File" with the new content.
2. On command line (DOS or Cygwin), use the mysqldump utility, e.g.
   mysqldump -u root -psomestring --hex-blob my_schemaname my_tablename > destination_file.sql
3. Open resulting destination_file.sql, copy and paste hex content strings to Flyway script.

QED

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative you can keep your BLOBs either in binary or hex format, and load them with a  Flyway Java-based migration.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Axel.  We do not currently use Java-based migration, but I might consider that soon, if I cannot progress this without it.

Comment: This is how we are doing it on Oracle. Similar mechanism for MySQL I hope https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43758759/how-to-insert-clob-blob-data-using-flyway/45104219#45104219

Comment: .. without a java migration.. just stored procedures

Answer (score 2):

From within MySQL Workbench 6.2 I went to **Server**->**Data Export** in the top menu. I selected the objects that what I wanted. Next I selected Export to **Self-Contained File**. Finally, I clicked on the **Advanced Options** button at the upper right side and then checked the **hex-blob** option.

Once I exported, the exported file had the INSERTS that I wanted with the hex blobs.

Answer (score 1):

Try DataExport feature in [dbForge Studio for MySQL](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/studio/). Click 'Export Data' command in popup menu on table in Database Explorer, select fields and rows you need to export, and press 'Export' button; you will get SQL script with INSERT statements.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Devart.  We do not use dbForge Studio, but I may try it shortly if I cannot make progress.